# Can I change TAdoQuery results after I have selected them from database

Tags: delphi, gridview, tadoquery

I have a gridview which is connected to a TAdoQuery.

I would like to change the values of a column for all the rows that I have filtered out.
Something like "check all" so it changes all the values for a column called "active" to True.

How would I do this?

Let's say I have something like

```
qry.filter := some filters here;
qry.filtered := true;
```

How can I change the values in the column "active" for all the filtered results like:

```
for 0 to qry.count -1 do
   qry.filtered.column(active) := True;
```

Comment: AFAIK, using the query, the only way will be iterating each one of them. If your query returns many data, the faster way would be grab all the keys and perform an update, directly to the database.

Comment: Are you looking for: `qry.First; While not qry.EOF do    begin      qry.Edit;      qry.FieldByName('active').value := true;      qry.Next;   end;` ?